# What spell level is "Thunderwave" when cast with the Fist of Four Thunders discipline as a Way of the Four Elements monk?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, monk, spellcasting

Fist of Four Thunders only says:

> You can spend 2 ki points to cast Thunderwave.

Is it always cast as a 1st level spell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### From 5th level on, you can spend extra ki to upcast *thunderwave*

See the text under the heading [Casting Elemental Spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheFourElements):

> Once you reach 5th level in this class, you can spend additional ki points to increase the level of an elemental discipline spell that you cast, provided that the spell has an enhanced effect at a higher level, as *burning hands* does. The spell’s level increases by 1 for each additional ki point you spend.

Taking your example, if you are a 5th-level monk and use Fist of Four Thunders to cast [*thunderwave*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thunderwave), you can spend 3 ki points to cast it as a 2nd-level spell (the discipline’s base cost of 2 ki points plus 1).

**Don't forget that the maximum number of points you can spend on a single spell is limited by your level.** You'll have to wait until you're a 9th-level Monk before you can cast *thunderwave* at third level, 13th-level Monk for the fourth-level spell, and 17th-level Monk for a fifth-level spell.

Answer (score 6):

## 1st level only at first, but can be upcast when you're a higher level monk

The Way of the Four Elements archetype (PHB, p. 80) describes that spells cast with ki can be upcast, but only after certain levels in monk.

> Once you reach 5th level in this class, you can spend additional ki points to increase the level of an elemental discipline spell that you cast, providing that the spell has an enhanced effect at a higher level, as *burning hands* does. The spell's level increases by 1 for each additional ki point you spend. For example, if you are a 5th-level monk and use Sweeping Cinder Strike to cast *burning hands*, you can spend 3 ki points to cast it as a 2nd-level spell (the discipline's base cost of 2 ki points plus 1).

It then shows you the "Spells and Ki Points" table showing you how many ki points you're allowed to spend at what level, which effectively caps how much you can upcast your spells by depending on what monk level you are.

So to answer your question directly, if you are only a 3rd level monk, then the spell *thunderwave* is always cast at 1st level. As you reach higher levels in monk, you can spend more ki points to upcast it.